# Modify SharePoint app link on office.com

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, app

By default, the SharePoint app link goes to the https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx page.
Is there any way to modify this? We would very much like it to point to the root home page, i.e. https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately this can’t be modified.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I posted a new idea on https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/325347-office-com-home-page/suggestions/39755581-modify-sharepoint-app-link-on-office-com.